# Setting the value of a dropdown box using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to set the `value` of a `dropdown` box using `JQuery`. This is my code but it is not working:

```
//Check if a box is ticked, if it is set the quantity:
$('.normalbulk').change(function(){
    if(this.checked){
    $('.order_amount').val('26');
    }
});
```

This is the `HTML`

```
<!-- If stock code contains "BULK" Display check box -->
                       <? $bulk = get_field('description', $product->ID);
                        if(strpos($bulk, 'Bulk') !== false): ?>
                         Normal Bulk:<input type="checkbox" name="normalbulk" value="bulk" class="normalbulk"> (26 Pallets)
                         Split Bulk: <input type="checkbox" name="splitbulk" value="bulk" class="splitbulk">  (16 Pallets)
                        <? endif; ?>
```

The idea is that when it is `checked` set the `value` of `order_amount` to 26 and when it is `unchecked` set the `value` to 0. The code I have at the moment does nothing.#

`order_amount` code

```
 Amount <select id="order_amount<?= $product->ID; ?>" name="amt" class="order_amount">
                        <option value="0">0</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        </select>
```

I appreciate all your answers guys, but it is still not working for me and I Can't understand why. This is my code now:

```
$(".normalbulk").change(function(){
   if(this.checked){
       console.log("checked");
       console.log($(this).closest('li').find('.order_amount').val());

   }else{
       console.log("unchecked");
       console.log($(this).closest('li').find('.order_amount').val());
   }
});
```

When the box is checked it outputs "checked" as expected, also prints the value of the closes `dropdown` but for some reason I just can't set the value which I do by changing the code to this:

```
       $(this).closest('li').find('.order_amount').val('26');
```

Found out why it wasn't working. I did not have a `select option` with a `value` of 26. Therefor it did not set the box to display anything. When I adjusted the code to display a `value` that did exist it worked perfectly using the solutions provided below.

Thank you for the help everyone

Comment: Is your JavaScript code in a document.ready function? What does the HTML for class="order_amount" look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is right you just have to write else portion here, like this:

```
$('.normalbulk').change(function(){
    if(this.checked){
      $('.order_amount').val(26);
    }
    else{
      $('.order_amount').val(0);
    }
});
```

**Edit**

Your dropdown must have value attribute with `26` vaule in it. So that you can select it with `.val()`

### [**Demo with select**](http://jsfiddle.net/2Udz7/2/)

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2Udz7/1/)

Comment: I realise I left the `else` portion out, but I had tried it like that and it still wasn't working, also your example is using a `textbox` I know it probably isn't a huge difference but I've literally got the exact same code as you except with a `dropdown`.

Comment: @Javacadabra hold on i'm working with dropdown and will return with the exact you want!

Comment: Thank you for your help @Dhaval, I got the code working with your answer and a little bit of tweaking on my end. I had a silly error in my code!!

Answer (score 1):

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5Sh4F/1/)**

Use event delegation- jQuery **[.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** if your checkboxes are added dynamically.

```
$(document).on('change','.normalbulk',function(){
    if(this.checked){
        $('.order_amount').val('26');
    }
    else{
        $('.order_amount').val(0);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of input type checkbox can only be true or false. You can change .splitbulk to input type hidden for example.

Comment: The value of an `input` element and the state are two different things. A checkbox can be `checked`  or not, but the value on the other hand can be _anything_.

Comment: @t.niese you are right, I'm sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

to assign value use this query .

```
$(".order_amountoption").filter(function () {
                                      return $(this).attr('value') == '26';
                                  }).attr('selected', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.normalbulk').click(function(){
    if(this.checked){
         $(".order_amount").val('26');
    }else {
         $(".order_amount").val('0');
    }
});
```